# Python Reverse Engineer List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Hello I am new to Python and Stackoverflow so please bear with me. I just recently discovered list comprehensions and wanted to "reverse engineer" a specific code to understand it better. In other words, how would the following code look in the regular block format:

```
    return [variable[i:i+10] for i in range(0,100,10)]
```

Comment: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ is a great resource, but in general, comprehensions in Python are of the form:

```
<expression> for <value> in <iterable> [if <criteria>]
```

So breaking out your example, we have:

- An expression: `variable[i:i+10]`
- A value `i`
- the iterable `range(0,100,10)`
- no criteria

The "expanded" form is:

```
result = []
for <value> in <iterable>:
    [if <criteria>:]
        result.append(<value>)
```

(generator, dict, and set comprehensions are all similar)

So taking your example, we get:

```
result = []
for i in range(0,100,10):
    result.append(variable[i:i+10])
return result
```